# apa7 citing ref needed tex studio+ tried with biblatex and biber compiler + issue round brackets around not generated around references

Tags: biblatex, citing, brackets, missing

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt]{report}
%=========================Preamble===================================

\usepackage{setspace} %for line spacing
\usepackage[american]{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage[style=apa, backend=biber]{biblatex}
\DeclareLanguageMapping{american}{american-apa}

\addbibresource{ots.bib}
\begin{document}
    \chapter{Introduction} Worldwide Artificial Insemination (AI) is the most common method for genetic upgradation of herds for economic characters. The success of AI depends upon many factors \cite{Sztein2018}. 
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

The round brackets around the reference is  missing in the output. It should be like this:

> ...depends upon many factors (Sztein et al., 2018)...

But the output is like this:

> ...depends upon many factors Sztein et al., 2018 ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With `biblatex` `\cite` gives a plain citation. With APA style you probably want to use either `\autocite` (which is set to `\parencite` by the style) or `\textcite`.

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt]{article}
\usepackage[american]{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage[style=apa, backend=biber]{biblatex}

\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\begin{document}
  Lorem \autocite{sigfridsson}
  
  Later it was shown by \textcite{sigfridsson} that

  Lorem \parencite{sigfridsson}

  Lorem \cite{sigfridsson}

  \printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image: Lorem (Sigfridsson & Ryde, 1998)//Later it was shown by Sigfridsson and Ryde (1998) that//Lorem (Sigfridsson & Ryde, 1998)//Lorem Sigfridsson and Ryde, 1998]

Comment: That is good, thanks its working.....I am using jabref....the document  is thesis..... was written with lots of citations.......what is the way out now....manually change \cite to \autocite...or any other command to serve the purpose

Comment: @MunishBedi Any good editor should have a search and replace function. It would be fairly safe to replace `\cite[` with `\autocite[` and `\cite{` with `\autocite{` (note the braces in each case to avoid replacing different macros with `\cite...` in their name). That can be done in under a minute.

Comment: Thanks...its all ok now

Comment: @MunishBedi If the answer helped you solve your problem, you may want to consider accepting it by clicking on the green checkmark on the top left to show that your problem is resolved. See https://tex.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers